# Facebook All_Mutual_Friends weirdness

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I just would like to share my experience using the all_mutual_friends for a feature I'm developing for a social app. It has been acting weird and I would like to know your experience using it.

So, let's consider two users for this application, User A and User B - which they are not friends on FB. And as soon as any of the users connects, I grab the context-id of it.

Then if User A is seeing User B profile, I request all_mutual_friends for UserA with graph api with the syntax `/{{context-id of UserB}}/all_mutual_friends`

In my tests, I have an User C, which is friend with both User A and User B.

And here comes the tragedy. Sometimes it works, graph api brings data about User C, sometimes not. I mean, it was working until yesterday and at moment is not working.

I also use the graph API tool to check and re-check information and it seems it is not the code itself, but with FB.

All users have their account created as they would be regular FB users, I'm not using FB test accounts, they are included as Developers of the app and the feature is only available in development mode.

Do you guys have faced this situation? Is it related to the feature not being approved to be used public or there is nothing to do with it?

Thank you!

Comment: did user C authorize the app too?

Comment: yep. User C is a developer.
Last week it was bringing the userC as the only mutual friend, but it stopped. On the Facebook bug report there is nothing recent, but I saw there was a case like that back in June or something. :(